# Power Automate - retrieve an inline Teams image from Microsoft graph

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I am attempting to retrieve and save an inline image from a Teams message. I have Power Automate reading the message and retrieving the image url. However, with Power Automate I just get 403 errors.

I am setting authentication in the HTTP GET
[image]

I can use [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to get the image, so I know the link is correct. I have created an app with permissions in Azure as shown here[image]

Am I missing a permission or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to perform the same HTTP request on your machine using some tool like Postman?

Sometimes I have timeout issues with Microsoft Flow HTTP requests due to issues with IP whitelisting. Flow uses different IPs you can [check it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config) and you may need to whitelist it first.